# Slider tema Sight e wp no funciona

Tags: wordpress

Hola a todos me gustaría que por favor me ayudaran a resolver un problema que tengo con una pag. web; el slider que viene por defecto con el tema sight de wordpress no funciona, y la verdad no se por que si anteriormente lo hacía sin problema alguno...
este es el link de la página : http://contarte.incp.org.co

Comment: Entre el momento en que funcionaba y ahora ¿Qué ha cambiado? No has activado nuevos plugins o actualizado la versión de WP?

Comment: pues modifique el archivo loop.php para quitar el autor de las entradas. Hice una copia de este archivo, pensé que ese había sido el problema pero cuando copie el archivo original nuevamente no hubo cambio alguno.

Comment: támbien instale un plugin que se llama cyclone slider para un pequeño banner de propaganda que está en el sidebar pero no creo que ese halla sido el problema

Comment: prueba desactivando todos los plugins a ver si funciona, y luego activándolos uno a uno a ver cuál es el que rompe el slider

Comment: Ok lo voy a interntar y le cuento como me fue gracias

Comment: Si desactive el  "cyclone slider" y funciono nuevamente, ahora el problema está en como lograr el mismo efecto sin que nada deje de funcionar???

Comment: tendrás que buscar otro plugin que no use el mismo espacio de nombres. Segundamente cyclone se adueña del nombre $.fn.cycle y pisa la función del slider original

Comment: Ok muchas gracias voy a buscar un nuevo plugin que no me genere este conflicto. Nuevamente gracias

Comment: @user22090 Si es posible marca una de las dos respuestas como "Solucionado" para que la pregunta no quede abierta. Para ello marcas la flecha de cotejo de la izquierda en cualquiera de las dos respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu theme de wordpress se carga el plugin jQuery Cycle

```
http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/themes/sight/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js?ver=20131219
```

Mientras que tu plugin cyclone slider carga el plugin jQuery Cicle 2

```
http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/plugins/cyclone-slider-2/libs/cycle2/jquery.cycle2.min.js
```

Son dos versiones distintas del mismo plugin (la primera del 2010, la segunda del 2013). Ambas usan el mismo espacio de nombres, de manera que tu plugin "pisa" la función `$.fn.cycle`  que había declarado el primero.

Hay dos soluciones acá:

- desactivas el plugin y buscas otro para reemplazar su funcionamiento
- adaptas la estructura de tu slider principal para funcionar con la versión 2013 de jQuery Cycle.

Lo segundo no debiera serte tan difícil si ya hicise un cycle para un banner de publicidad. Básicamente tendrías que intervenir el template para tener la misma estructura y clases.

Comment: Disculpe mi ignorancia pero podría explicarme lo de invertir el template...

Answer (score 0):

Hay un conflicto con uno de estos plugins:

> ```
> <script type='text/javascript' src='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/plugins/cyclone-slider-2/libs/cycle2/jquery.cycle2.min.js?ver=2.12.4'></script>
> <script type='text/javascript' src='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/plugins/cyclone-slider-2/libs/cycle2/jquery.cycle2.carousel.min.js?ver=2.12.4'></script>
> <script type='text/javascript' src='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/plugins/cyclone-slider-2/libs/cycle2/jquery.cycle2.swipe.min.js?ver=2.12.4'></script>
> <script type='text/javascript' src='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/plugins/cyclone-slider-2/libs/cycle2/jquery.cycle2.tile.min.js?ver=2.12.4'></script>
> <script type='text/javascript' src='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/plugins/cyclone-slider-2/libs/cycle2/jquery.cycle2.video.min.js?ver=2.12.4'></script>
> <script type='text/javascript' src='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/plugins/cyclone-slider-2/templates/dark/script.js?ver=2.12.4'></script>
> ```

**ELIMINADO TODOS ESOS SCRIPTS EL SLIDER FUNCIONA PERFECTAMENTE**

Prueba dándola a Ejecutar. Si lo quieres ver mejor le das a Ampliar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>ContArte | Para los jóvenes contadores</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-language" content="es-ES" />
 <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/themes/sight/images/favico.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
 <link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s.w.org' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="ContArte &raquo; Feed" href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="ContArte &raquo; RSS de los comentarios" href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/comments/feed/" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
  window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/2.2.1\/72x72\/","ext":".png","svgUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/2.2.1\/svg\/","svgExt":".svg","source":{"concatemoji":"http:\/\/contarte.incp.org.co\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.7.2"}};
  !function(a,b,c){function d(a){var b,c,d,e,f=String.fromCharCode;if(!k||!k.fillText)return!1;switch(k.clearRect(0,0,j.width,j.height),k.textBaseline="top",k.font="600 32px Arial",a){case"flag":return k.fillText(f(55356,56826,55356,56819),0,0),!(j.toDataURL().length<3e3)&&(k.clearRect(0,0,j.width,j.height),k.fillText(f(55356,57331,65039,8205,55356,57096),0,0),b=j.toDataURL(),k.clearRect(0,0,j.width,j.height),k.fillText(f(55356,57331,55356,57096),0,0),c=j.toDataURL(),b!==c);case"emoji4":return k.fillText(f(55357,56425,55356,57341,8205,55357,56507),0,0),d=j.toDataURL(),k.clearRect(0,0,j.width,j.height),k.fillText(f(55357,56425,55356,57341,55357,56507),0,0),e=j.toDataURL(),d!==e}return!1}function e(a){var c=b.createElement("script");c.src=a,c.defer=c.type="text/javascript",b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c)}var f,g,h,i,j=b.createElement("canvas"),k=j.getContext&&j.getContext("2d");for(i=Array("flag","emoji4"),c.supports={everything:!0,everythingExceptFlag:!0},h=0;h<i.length;h++)c.supports[i[h]]=d(i[h]),c.supports.everything=c.supports.everything&&c.supports[i[h]],"flag"!==i[h]&&(c.supports.everythingExceptFlag=c.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&c.supports[i[h]]);c.supports.everythingExceptFlag=c.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&!c.supports.flag,c.DOMReady=!1,c.readyCallback=function(){c.DOMReady=!0},c.supports.everything||(g=function(){c.readyCallback()},b.addEventListener?(b.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",g,!1),a.addEventListener("load",g,!1)):(a.attachEvent("onload",g),b.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===b.readyState&&c.readyCallback()})),f=c.source||{},f.concatemoji?e(f.concatemoji):f.wpemoji&&f.twemoji&&(e(f.twemoji),e(f.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);
 </script>
 <style type="text/css">
img.wp-smiley,
img.emoji {
display: inline !important;
border: none !important;
box-shadow: none !important;
height: 1em !important;
width: 1em !important;
margin: 0 .07em !important;
vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
background: none !important;
padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='contact-form-7-css'  href='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=4.7' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='sight-style-css'  href='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/themes/sight/style.css?ver=4.7.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='sight-ie-css'  href='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/themes/sight/ie.css?ver=20131217' type='text/css' media='all' />
<![endif]-->
<link rel='stylesheet' id='lana-carousel-css'  href='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/plugins/lana-widgets//assets/css/lana-carousel.css?ver=1.0.5' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='magnific-popup-css'  href='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/plugins/lana-widgets//assets/css/jquery.magnific-popup.min.css?ver=1.1.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='cyclone-template-style-dark-0-css'  href='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/plugins/cyclone-slider-2/templates/dark/style.css?ver=2.12.4' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='cyclone-template-style-default-0-css'  href='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/plugins/cyclone-slider-2/templates/default/style.css?ver=2.12.4' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='cyclone-template-style-standard-0-css'  href='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/plugins/cyclone-slider-2/templates/standard/style.css?ver=2.12.4' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='cyclone-template-style-thumbnails-0-css'  href='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/plugins/cyclone-slider-2/templates/thumbnails/style.css?ver=2.12.4' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css'  href='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/plugins/lana-widgets//assets/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=3.3.5' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/themes/sight/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js?ver=20131219'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/themes/sight/js/jquery.cookie.js?ver=20131219'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/plugins/lana-widgets//assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js?ver=1.1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/plugins/lana-widgets//assets/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=3.3.5'></script>
<link rel='https://api.w.org/' href='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-json/' />
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.7.2" />
<link rel="icon" href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/cropped-cropped-logo-contarte-blanco-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/cropped-cropped-logo-contarte-blanco-192x192.png" sizes="192x192" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/cropped-cropped-logo-contarte-blanco-180x180.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/cropped-cropped-logo-contarte-blanco-270x270.png" />
 <style type="text/css" id="wp-custom-css">
  /*
Puedes añadir tu propio CSS aquí.

div.post-meta{
display-none
}
Haz clic en el icono de ayuda de arriba para averiguar más.
*/  </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 (function($) {
  $(function() {
   $('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollHorz',
    timeout: 7000,
    next: '#rarr',
    prev: '#larr'
   });
  })
 })(jQuery)
 </script>
  </head>
<body class="home blog"style="background-color: #01b2bf;">
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header clear">
   <div class="logo">
    <a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co"><img src="http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/cropped-logo-contarte-blanco.png" alt="ContArte"/></a>
   </div>

   
   <div class="search_form">
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="http://contarte.incp.org.co">
 <fieldset>
  <input name="s" type="text" onfocus="if(this.value=='Buscar') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Buscar';" value="Buscar" />
  <button type="submit"></button>
 </fieldset>
</form>
</div>

   <div class="menu"><ul id="menu-primary" class=""><li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-8"><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/acerca-de/">¿Qué es Contarte?</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-9"><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/contacto/">Contacto</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-69" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-69"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.incp.org.co/">INCP</a></li>
</ul></div>   </div>

  <div class="nav"><ul id="dd" class="dd"><li id="menu-item-187" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-187"><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/">Inicio</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-24"><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/category/noticias/">Noticias</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-195" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-195"><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/category/los-contadores/">Los Contadores</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children parent menu-item-68"><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/tag/investigacion/">Investigación</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-364" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-364"><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/que-esta-investigando/">¿Qué está investigando?</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-103" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-103"><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/category/eventos/">Eventos</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-140" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children parent menu-item-140"><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/vacantes/">Vacantes</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-459" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-459"><a href="http://www.incp.org.co/services/category/oferta-laboral/profesionales/">Profesionales</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-460" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-460"><a href="http://www.incp.org.co/services/category/oferta-laboral/estudiantes/">Estudiantes</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-461" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-461"><a href="http://www.incp.org.co/services/envianos-tu-oferta-laboral/">Envíanos tu oferta laboral</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-177" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-177"><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/micontador/">¡MICOntador!</a></li>
</ul></div>
  
<div class="slideshow">
<div id="slideshow">


 <div class="slide clear">
  <div class="post">
   <a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/una-colombiana-entre-los-5-mejores-emprendedores-de-latinoamerica/"><img width="625" height="290" src="http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/jimena_top-625x290.jpg" class="attachment-slide size-slide wp-post-image" alt="Una colombiana entre los 5 mejores emprendedores de Latinoamérica" title="Una colombiana entre los 5 mejores emprendedores de Latinoamérica" /></a>    <div class="post-category"><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/category/noticias/" rel="category tag">Noticias</a></div>
   <h2><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/una-colombiana-entre-los-5-mejores-emprendedores-de-latinoamerica/">Una colombiana entre los 5 mejores emprendedores de Latinoamérica</a></h2>

   <div class="post-meta">by <span class="post-author"><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/author/carolina-moncayo/" title="Posts by carolina.moncayo">carolina.moncayo</a></span> on <span class="post-date">Ene 17, 2017</span> &bull;
    <a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/una-colombiana-entre-los-5-mejores-emprendedores-de-latinoamerica/#respond"class="comments_popup_link">No Comments</a>         </div>
   <div class="post-content">Conozca un poco sobre esta CEO y su proyecto ecológico, sano y nacido en el país.</div>
  </div>
 </div>


 <div class="slide clear">
  <div class="post">
   <a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/que-tan-contador-es-el-contador-de-el-contador/"><img width="640" height="290" src="http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/bn-qh187_boxoff_gr_20161016161012-640x290.jpg" class="attachment-slide size-slide wp-post-image" alt="¿Qué tan contador es el contador de &#039;El Contador&#039;?" title="¿Qué tan contador es el contador de &#039;El Contador&#039;?" /></a>    <div class="post-category"><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/category/noticias/" rel="category tag">Noticias</a></div>
   <h2><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/que-tan-contador-es-el-contador-de-el-contador/">¿Qué tan contador es el contador de &#8216;El Contador&#8217;?</a></h2>

   <div class="post-meta">by <span class="post-author"><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/author/carolina-moncayo/" title="Posts by carolina.moncayo">carolina.moncayo</a></span> on <span class="post-date">Ene 4, 2017</span> &bull;
    <a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/que-tan-contador-es-el-contador-de-el-contador/#respond"class="comments_popup_link">No Comments</a>         </div>
   <div class="post-content">Aunque suelen decir que los contadores son aburridos, Christian Wolff llega que una cosa es tener una profesión monótona y otra relacionarlos con aburrimiento.</div>
  </div>
 </div>


 <div class="slide clear">
  <div class="post">
   <a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/sabe-pedir-su-tarjeta-profesional-de-contador/"><img width="640" height="290" src="http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/tarjeta-profesional-contador-640x290.jpg" class="attachment-slide size-slide wp-post-image" alt="¿Sabe pedir su tarjeta profesional de contador?" title="¿Sabe pedir su tarjeta profesional de contador?" /></a>    <div class="post-category"><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/category/noticias/" rel="category tag">Noticias</a></div>
   <h2><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/sabe-pedir-su-tarjeta-profesional-de-contador/">¿Sabe pedir su tarjeta profesional de contador?</a></h2>

   <div class="post-meta">by <span class="post-author"><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/author/carolina-moncayo/" title="Posts by carolina.moncayo">carolina.moncayo</a></span> on <span class="post-date">Dic 9, 2016</span> &bull;
    <a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/sabe-pedir-su-tarjeta-profesional-de-contador/#respond"class="comments_popup_link">No Comments</a>         </div>
   <div class="post-content">Acá le contamos la experiencia necesaria para pedir el documento que lo acredita como contador ante el estado, le aclaramos algunas dudas que circulan y le anticipamos noticias relacionadas.</div>
  </div>
 </div>


</div>

<a href="javascript: void(0);" id="larr"></a>
<a href="javascript: void(0);" id="rarr"></a>
</div>

  <!-- Container -->
  <div id="container" class="clear">
   <!-- Content -->
   <div id="content">

<div class="content-title">
Ultimas Entradas <a href="javascript: void(0);" id="mode"></a>
</div>



<div id="loop" class="list clear">


 <div class="post clear post-279 type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-noticias tag-baruch-lev tag-contaduria-publica tag-feng-gu tag-investigacion tag-libro tag-the-end-of-accounting" id="post_279">
     <a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/se-acabo-la-contaduria-tradicional/" class="thumb"><img width="290" height="290" src="http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/board-1820678_640-290x290.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="¡Se acabó la contaduría!... tradicional" title="¡Se acabó la contaduría!... tradicional" srcset="http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/board-1820678_640-290x290.jpg 290w, http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/board-1820678_640-50x50.jpg 50w" sizes="(max-width: 290px) 100vw, 290px" /></a>
  
  <div class="post-category"><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/category/noticias/" rel="category tag">Noticias</a></div>
  <h2><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/se-acabo-la-contaduria-tradicional/">¡Se acabó la contaduría!&#8230; tradicional</a></h2>

<!--    <div class="post-meta">   </div> -->
  
  <div class="post-content">Baruch Lev y Feng Gu, profesores de la NYU Stern School of Business y de la Universidad de Buffalo, escribieron un libro contable apocalíptico ¿o no?  </div>
 </div>


 <div class="post clear post-255 type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-investigacion tag-impuesto-de-renta tag-investigacion tag-redistribucion tag-universidad tag-universidad-nacional" id="post_255">
     <a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/impuesto-de-renta-dime-como-opera-y-te-dire-como-redistribuye/" class="thumb"><img width="290" height="290" src="http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/abacus-1866497_960_720-290x290.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Impuesto de renta: &quot;Dime cómo opera y te diré cómo redistribuye&quot;" title="Impuesto de renta: &quot;Dime cómo opera y te diré cómo redistribuye&quot;" srcset="http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/abacus-1866497_960_720-290x290.jpg 290w, http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/abacus-1866497_960_720-50x50.jpg 50w" sizes="(max-width: 290px) 100vw, 290px" /></a>
  
  <div class="post-category"><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/category/investigacion/" rel="category tag">Investigación</a></div>
  <h2><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/impuesto-de-renta-dime-como-opera-y-te-dire-como-redistribuye/">Impuesto de renta: &#8220;Dime cómo opera y te diré cómo redistribuye&#8221;</a></h2>

<!--    <div class="post-meta">   </div> -->
  
  <div class="post-content">El funcionamiento de este impuesto tiene implicaciones directas sobre la manera como se reparte el dinero obtenido.</div>
 </div>


 <div class="post clear post-233 type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-eventos tag-evento tag-internacional tag-universidad tag-universidad-de-los-andes" id="post_233">
     <a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/que-tener-en-consideracion-para-internacionalizarse-desde-america-latina/" class="thumb"><img width="290" height="290" src="http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/281116_bannerinterno_internacionalizar-290x290.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="¿Qué tener en consideración para internacionalizarse desde América Latina?" title="¿Qué tener en consideración para internacionalizarse desde América Latina?" srcset="http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/281116_bannerinterno_internacionalizar-290x290.jpg 290w, http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/281116_bannerinterno_internacionalizar-50x50.jpg 50w" sizes="(max-width: 290px) 100vw, 290px" /></a>
  
  <div class="post-category"><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/category/eventos/" rel="category tag">Eventos</a></div>
  <h2><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/que-tener-en-consideracion-para-internacionalizarse-desde-america-latina/">¿Qué tener en consideración para internacionalizarse desde América Latina?</a></h2>

<!--    <div class="post-meta">   </div> -->
  
  <div class="post-content">Fecha: 1 de diciembre Lugar: virtual | La Universidad de los Andes lo invita a este evento virtual gratuito.
</div>
 </div>


 <div class="post clear post-219 type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-noticias tag-empresas tag-estudiantes tag-estudio tag-millenials tag-trabajo" id="post_219">
     <a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/aqui-quieren-trabajar-los-millenials/" class="thumb"><img width="290" height="290" src="http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/millenials-trabajo-290x290.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Aquí quieren trabajar los millenials" title="Aquí quieren trabajar los millenials" srcset="http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/millenials-trabajo-290x290.jpg 290w, http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/millenials-trabajo-50x50.jpg 50w" sizes="(max-width: 290px) 100vw, 290px" /></a>
  
  <div class="post-category"><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/category/noticias/" rel="category tag">Noticias</a></div>
  <h2><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/aqui-quieren-trabajar-los-millenials/">Aquí quieren trabajar los millenials</a></h2>

<!--    <div class="post-meta">   </div> -->
  
  <div class="post-content">Diferentes investigaciones revelan las empresas favoritas de los jóvenes profesionales y estudiantes a punto de graduarse. Google aparece en todos los conteos. En Colombia escasean las compañías de tecnología.</div>
 </div>


 <div class="post clear post-188 type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-los-contadores tag-contador tag-historia tag-luca-pacioli tag-perfil" id="post_188">
     <a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/luca-pacioli-el-primer-contador/" class="thumb"><img width="290" height="290" src="http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/pacioli-1-290x290.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Luca Pacioli, el primer contador" title="Luca Pacioli, el primer contador" srcset="http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/pacioli-1-290x290.jpg 290w, http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/pacioli-1-50x50.jpg 50w" sizes="(max-width: 290px) 100vw, 290px" /></a>
  
  <div class="post-category"><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/category/los-contadores/" rel="category tag">Los Contadores</a></div>
  <h2><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/luca-pacioli-el-primer-contador/">Luca Pacioli, el primer contador</a></h2>

<!--    <div class="post-meta">   </div> -->
  
  <div class="post-content">El 'padre' de la profesión trabajó con Da Vinci y se interesaba en el ajedrez y la geometría. Un libro suyo solo apareció hasta el siglo XXI en una biblioteca europea. Pacioli está lejos de ser un personaje aburrido.</div>
 </div>


 <div class="post clear post-79 type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-eventos tag-evento tag-facultad-de-ciencias-economicas-y-administrativas tag-gratuito tag-tail-sharot tag-the-science-of-optimism tag-universidad-javeriana" id="post_79">
     <a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/la-ciencia-del-optimismo-en-la-javeriana/" class="thumb"><img width="290" height="290" src="http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/tail-sharot-290x290.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="&#039;La ciencia del optimismo&#039; en la Javeriana" title="&#039;La ciencia del optimismo&#039; en la Javeriana" srcset="http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/tail-sharot-290x290.jpg 290w, http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/tail-sharot-50x50.jpg 50w" sizes="(max-width: 290px) 100vw, 290px" /></a>
  
  <div class="post-category"><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/category/eventos/" rel="category tag">Eventos</a></div>
  <h2><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/la-ciencia-del-optimismo-en-la-javeriana/">&#8216;La ciencia del optimismo&#8217; en la Javeriana</a></h2>

<!--    <div class="post-meta">   </div> -->
  
  <div class="post-content">Fecha: 1 de diciembre
Lugar: Centro Javeriano de Formación Deportiva |
 Una conferencia dictada por la profesora del University College London.
</div>
 </div>


 <div class="post clear post-48 type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-investigacion tag-estudiantes tag-futuro tag-investigacion tag-universidad tag-universidad-del-valle" id="post_48">
     <a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/el-cambio-de-actitud-necesario-en-los-estudiantes-de-contaduria/" class="thumb"><img width="290" height="290" src="http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/photo-1456406644174-8ddd4cd52a06-290x290.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="El cambio de actitud necesario en los estudiantes de contaduría" title="El cambio de actitud necesario en los estudiantes de contaduría" srcset="http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/photo-1456406644174-8ddd4cd52a06-290x290.jpg 290w, http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/photo-1456406644174-8ddd4cd52a06-50x50.jpg 50w" sizes="(max-width: 290px) 100vw, 290px" /></a>
  
  <div class="post-category"><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/category/investigacion/" rel="category tag">Investigación</a></div>
  <h2><a href="http://contarte.incp.org.co/el-cambio-de-actitud-necesario-en-los-estudiantes-de-contaduria/">El cambio de actitud necesario en los estudiantes de contaduría</a></h2>

<!--    <div class="post-meta">   </div> -->
  
  <div class="post-content">El problema de que muchos futuros contadores llegan a las aulas con experiencia en su campo es que no le ven conexión a la parte teórica y a la práctica. </div>
 </div>


</div>






  </body>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/plugins/cyclone-slider-2/templates/thumbnails/script.js?ver=2.12.4'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-content/plugins/cyclone-slider-2/js/client.js?ver=2.12.4'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://contarte.incp.org.co/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.7.2'></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Perdón no entiendo muy bien lo que debo hacer.

Comment: @user22090 Si pulses en Ejecutar (botón azul) verás que el slider funciona. Sólo que he pegado un fragmento de código de tu página sin los archivos javascript que tu plugin cyclone-slider-2 agrega. Evidentemente el conflicto es con ese plugin. Como se ha dicho en otra respuesta, cyclone parece ser compatible con tu slider. Entonces, o bien tratas de actualizarlo si hay actualizaciones disponibles o usas otro plugin que hago lo mismo pero que no sea conflictivo.